# Vivado SDK doesn't recognize the functions inside #include "math.h"

Tags: c++, math.h, vivado, vivado-hls

I wrote a simple project in Vivado SDK in order to test my HW-platform developed in Vivado. 
My problem is that **the SDK doesn't recognise the sin() function**. I've included the **"math.h"** library without any error, the program recognise the library where the sin() function is included (I checked it by my own).

I obtain this error:

```
C:\PATH...\Debug/../src/helloworld.c: undefined reference to `sin' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) and it is too general so it was useless to solve my problem. It's clear there is a problem of library but it's not clear how to solve it specifically in Vivado SDK.

I'm working with:
  OS:         Windows 7

Vivado:            2016.1

Vivado SDK: 2016.1

Any solution???

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was explain [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/52971.html) in the Xilinx forum, you can add in the **Arm v7 gcc liker** the “m” value.

In order to set correctly this value navigate from the toolbox in 
**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Arm v7 gcc linker -> Libraries -> Libraries(-l) -> Add…**
and here you can add the value “m”. This is valid for all the mathematical function that you want to use in your project.

[image]

You should see something like this in the end.

Comment: It should work for some earlier versions as well. And for Vivado 2016.2

Comment: Many thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. My project doesn't include the "arm v7 gcc linker" settings, just the compiler: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCKWQ.png). Is this possibly because I'm using the WebPACK license or do I need to add something else?

Comment: It seems you are not in the same window.

Comment: I am getting error "math function 'pow' is not supported for synthesis" while using pow function in my C code in HLS 2015.2. Can anybody help me to solve the error? I tried the same [trick](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/52971.html) but it is not working. 

Thank you.